# compressing trailing padding space in struct composition or inheritance

Tags: c++

Consider the´following code:

```
struct A {
    double d;
    float a;
};
static_assert(sizeof(A) == 2 * sizeof(double), "");

struct B : A {
    float b;
};
static_assert(sizeof(B) == sizeof(A), ""); //Fails

struct C {
    A a;
    float b;
};
static_assert(sizeof(C) == sizeof(A), ""); //Fails
```

Is there a (preferably portable) way to arrange that b lives in the unused trailing padding space of A?

I could modify A by adding an anticipatory data member to the end, or I could placement-construct b into A's padding space, but there must be a better way to do that.

Maybe pragma pack (but multiple data members of A should stay aligned and not be compressed)? Or a properly placed alignas?

Comment: It would be possible using compiler-specific pragmas or attributes to pack the structures, but not without losing the alignment of the members. No standard way of doing it though.

Comment: Try adding an empty base class: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pKXKfaCH9oj90wGY -- I have no idea why this works, btw.

Answer (score 0):

Is alternative approach eligible?
Like this:

```
struct A {
    char buf[100];
    float *a() {
        return (float *)&buf[0];
    }
};

struct B : A {
    float *b() {
        return (float *)&buf[4];
    }
};
static_assert(sizeof(B) == sizeof(A), ""); // should pass
```